# Mongodb .net async await

Tags: .net, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-.net-driver

Does the mongodb .net driver offer support for async/await operations? I can't seem to find any info on this.
I'm looking for something like EntityFramework has:

```
ToListAsync(), FindAsync(), CountAsync()
```

Is this supported?

Comment: I couldn't find any solution, did you? thanks

Comment: I haven't used MongoDB in years, but it appears that the new drivers offer async support https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.0 Driver is released. Check it out:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

Nuget:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver

Answer (score 4):

I've made some changes in the official driver to make it async as possible. Basically, I've changed the `MongoConnection` class to use the `NetworkStream` async methods (WriteAsync and ReadAsync) and propagated the changes all by the code.

Besides that, I've added the async LINQ methods like the EF6 (I actually took the extensions from the EF code and adapted to the mongo driver).

It's not production quality, but it's working.

https://github.com/andrebires/mongo-csharp-driver