# ASP.NET Web API 2 Async action methods with Task.Run performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm trying to benchmark (using Apache bench) a couple of ASP.NET Web API 2.0 endpoints. One of which is synchronous and one async.

```
        [Route("user/{userId}/feeds")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<NewsFeedItem> GetNewsFeedItemsForUser(string userId)
        {
            return _newsFeedService.GetNewsFeedItemsForUser(userId);
        }

        [Route("user/{userId}/feeds/async")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<NewsFeedItem>> GetNewsFeedItemsForUserAsync(string userId)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => _newsFeedService.GetNewsFeedItemsForUser(userId));
        }
```

After watching [Steve Sanderson's presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2287) I issued the following command `ab -n 100 -c 10 http://localhost....` to each endpoint.

I was surprised as the benchmarks for each endpoint seemed to be approximately the same.

Going off what Steve explained I was expecting that the async endpoint would be more performant because it would release thread pool threads back to the thread pool immediately, thus making them available for other requests and improving throughput. But the numbers seem exactly the same.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `await Task.Run` to create **"async"** WebApi is a bad idea - you will still use a thread, and even from [the same thread pool used for requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697692/3745022).

It will lead to some unpleasant moments described in good details [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html):

> - Extra (unnecessary) thread switching to the Task.Run thread pool thread. Similarly, when that thread finishes the request, it has to
>     enter the request context (which is not an actual thread switch but
>     does have overhead).
> - Extra (unnecessary) garbage is created. Asynchronous programming is a tradeoff: you get increased responsiveness at the expense of higher
>     memory usage. In this case, you end up creating more garbage for the
>     asynchronous operations that is totally unnecessary.
> - The ASP.NET thread pool heuristics are thrown off by Task.Run “unexpectedly” borrowing a thread pool thread. I don’t have a lot of
>     experience here, but my gut instinct tells me that the heuristics
>     should recover well if the unexpected task is really short and would
>     not handle it as elegantly if the unexpected task lasts more than two
>     seconds.
> - ASP.NET is not able to terminate the request early, i.e., if the client disconnects or the request times out. In the synchronous case,
>     ASP.NET knew the request thread and could abort it. In the
>     asynchronous case, ASP.NET is not aware that the secondary thread pool
>     thread is “for” that request. It is possible to fix this by using
>     cancellation tokens, but that’s outside the scope of this blog post.

Basically, you do not allow any asynchrony to the ASP.NET - you just hide the CPU-bound synchronous code behind the async facade. `Async` on its own is ideal for I/O bound code, because it allows to utilize CPU (threads) at their top efficiency (no blocking for I/O), but when you have Compute-bound code, you will still have to utilize CPU to the same extent.

And taking into account the additional overhead from `Task` and context switching you will get even worser results than with simple sync controller methods.

**HOW TO MAKE IT TRULY ASYNC:**

`GetNewsFeedItemsForUser` method shall be turned into `async`.

```
    [Route("user/{userId}/feeds/async")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<NewsFeedItem>> GetNewsFeedItemsForUserAsync(string userId)
    {
        return await _newsFeedService.GetNewsFeedItemsForUser(userId);
    }
```

To do it:

- If it is some library method then look for its `async` variant (if there are none - bad luck, you'll have to search for some competing analogue).
- If it is your custom method using file system or database then leverage their async facilities to create async API for the method.

Comment: Ok, I get that Task.Run is a bad idea in ASP.NET because it uses a thread from the thread pool. I suppose my questions now are (1) Should I be trying to hand off this work to another thread? my call to ```_newsFeedService.GetNewsFeedItemsForUser(userId)``` is a call to a database, which I'm guessing is network and I/O, not CPU bound. (2) If it is a good idea, how should that code be written? All the examples I see don't show that bit of the code. Any examples would be really useful.

Comment: @SimonLomax Just search for "C# entity framework async" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx if you use entity framework or "C# database async" -http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronous-database-calls-with-task-based-asynchronous-programming-model-tap-in-asp-net-mvc-4 if you use standard ADO.

Comment: I'm actually using mongo and the c# driver for mongo, not Entity Framework. Regardless of that, from what your saying, unless the calls I'm making from my custom method ```_newsFeedService.GetNewsFeedItemsForUser(userId);``` are async then there's no point in trying to make my controller action method async.

Comment: @SimonLomax It seems that MongoDB has some async API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740329/mongodb-net-async-await. But you will obviously have to change the `GetNewsFeedItemsForUser` method to work through this API. It may become a nontrivial but hardly very difficult change.