# Background workers in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, backgroundworker

I'm trying to figure out how it comes that my request to an API call is waiting for my backgroundworkers to be completed.

This is my jobManager:

```
public class JobManager {
public List<AbstractJob> Jobs;

public JobManager() {
  Jobs = new List<AbstractJob>();
}

public int newTestJob() {
  var job = new TestJob();
  job.Name = "TestJob";
  Jobs.Add(job);
  return job.Id;
}

public void startJob(int id) {
  var job = Jobs.Where(j => j.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
  if (job == null) throw new Exception("not found");

  job.Execute();
}

public string statusJob(int id) {
  var job = Jobs.Where(j => j.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
  if (job == null) throw new Exception("not found");

  return job.Status;
}

public List<AbstractJob> runningJobs() {
  return Jobs.Where(j => j.Status == "Running").ToList();
}
}
```

this is a IJob

```
public interface IJob {
  void Execute();
}
```

this is AbstractJob

```
public abstract class AbstractJob : IJob {
  static int counter = 0;
  protected BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
  public int Id;
  public string Status;
  public string Name;

  public AbstractJob() {
    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    Id = counter;
    _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    _bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    _bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    _bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
    _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    _bw.ReportProgress(0, "Idle");
  }

  public virtual string Describe() {
    return "Not much is known about this four legged animal!";
  }

  public void Execute() {
    _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
  private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    this.Status = e.UserState.ToString();
  }

  private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    if ((e.Cancelled == true)) {
      this.Status = "Canceled";
    } else if (!(e.Error == null)) {
      this.Status = "Error";

    } else {
      this.Status = "Done";
    }
  }
  public abstract void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e);
}
```

And say that this is my job:

```
public class TestJob : AbstractJob {
  public override void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000); // representing some actual code that takes time
  }
}
```

So I wanted in my controller to create 10 jobs and return the Id's while the tasks are running in the background.

```
public IEnumerable<int> Get() {
  var ids = new List<int>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var id = jobm.newTestJob();
    jobm.startJob(id);
    ids.Add(id);
  }

  return ids;
}
```

This all seem to work great, except that the request is waiting on the sleeptimer in the job. although when I place a breakpoint on `return ids` in my controller; it hit's it very fast (so the async is working)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should have the message:
"An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending."
[It is considered as dangerous to launch background tasks without awaiting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805796/asp-net-controller-an-asynchronous-module-or-handler-completed-while-an-asynchr)

You should use the TaskParallelLibrary - async/await do do that and properly wait for all the Tasks to return:

```
 public async Task Get()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                   //your code here
                }));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
```

If you are doing FireAndForget you can use the new [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)  from framework 4.5.2.

Also check out this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168188/asp-net-web-api-2-async-action-methods-with-task-run-performance). It is better to use the native async methods and to transform the whole chain to async instead of simply doing "Task.Run".

Comment: Thanks, trying now a different approach (via windows service and SQL table)