# C# Web api get request per minute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, request

I'm getting data in xml form from a web address with C #. My question is, the data at this address is refreshed every minute.
How do I send a request to this address every minute with C #?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background workers in WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475970/background-workers-in-webapi)

Comment: Use  timer .follow the link    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.timer?view=netframework-4.8